# SVN 'path not found' error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

SVN is acting really strangely ... I'm just trying to add a file ... and am curiously getting the following error.

> '/fin/trunk/Proj.Web/Areas/App1' path not found

I'm using tortoiseSVN and all I did was tried to add a new file to the repository. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you confirmed the URl of the repository you are trying to commit? (You can use the repo browser in Tortoise to get the correct URL). Also worth checking if you have already added the parent directory of the file to the repository as yet. Sometimes (if you are using http protocol to access the repo) it is worth verifying the repository URL (from repo browser) and sticking it to the internet browser to see if you are able to access it via the browser. Helps see if the server is up etc., Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the repository URL is correct. The parent directory doesn't seem to get added in the list of unversioned files for some reason, even if I uncheck "show unversioned". For a reference, I'm trying to add a few files that are two levels deep in a new directory structure (/App1/Controllers/PanelController.cs). A similar file/folder structure was able to add with no issue.

Comment: You can look into the apache error logs on the server (IMO its a great place to start especially for usage errors from TortoiseSVN). The Tortoise errors are not always helpful in figuring out the underlying problem, but the apache logs are more eloquent.

Comment: Also pay special attention to the case of the url in use, as opposed to what shows up in the error logs.

Answer (score 2):

Can't vote yet, but wanted to add that Critical Skill's LAST comment was what worked for me: there was a case-sensitivity issue with my URI that I didn't know of (two letters in the branch name needed to be capitalized).  I think that's a bit silly (subversion should canonicalize naming to all-lower or something), but fixed it and suddenly the branch was found properly.